# Use of Jmap with Jre

Tags: memory-leaks, java

I have a java application running on Linux system. Currently we are facing some issues with the application and as per the initial investigation we observe that there are some memory leakage in java application.

The application is running with Java JRE

```
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_11-b03)
```

I have been suggested to use jmap for memory leak. My question is, I have to move application on JDK from jre or I can just install jdk and use jmap for investigation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use jmap on a JRE - JRE and JDK share the same run-time environment, the difference is just the tools supplied (having said that, I always insist on the JDK being present on our production servers :-)).

Personally, I'd recommend taking a memory dump and perusing it off-line with Eclipse's awesomely rocking Memory Analyzer Tool, though.

http://www.eclipse.org/mat/